# How to use python to upload files to websites automatically?

Tags: javascript, python, upload

Recently, I am using Memrise(A vocabulary memorizing App ).
I met a problem.

As you can see the pic below [image]

on the right side, I can upload audio files so that I can hear pronunciations while using this App and indeed I have these audios but it would cost me a lot of time to upload them one by one.

Therefore, I want to ask, can I use python or other tools to upload audio automatically instead of doing it by myself. Please give me a hint or some thoughts.

Comment: What kind of App it is? Webpage?

Comment: You mean "it's a website and you want to upload your audios in one shot through running script ?"

Comment: It is a webpage App. I want to upload audios in one shot through running script.

Comment: I am thinking if python is the ideal to do this task, but haven't figure out how to achieve that.